# Callback on sockets in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, openssl

Is there any way to **associate callback functions with sockets in Linux**?

For example,when the function

```c
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)peeraddr, sizeof(*peeraddr))
```

has connected the client with the server, is there a way to associate a function "`afterRecv`" with the socket of name `sock` such that after function `recv` has read some data from `sock`, `afterRecv` gets called?

That `sock` is of blocking type. This is due to the many internal `send/recv` calls on `sock` during the handshake period of `OpenSSL`.

If I modify `OpenSSL`, it would be cumbersome to modify every `recv`. So I wondered, if I can add a callback instead.

The flow should be:

1. `connect` to socket
2. `recv` function
3. When `recv` has read data, `afterRecv` gets called as a callback on `recv`

Comment: As you seem to be planing to recompile OpenSSL's sources, replacing `recv()` by your own version (wrapping around the original `recv()`) would do the job, wouldn't it?

Comment: @alk Yes, that seems a good option.

Comment: if you're open to using C++ the [boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/asio/) library has fantastic support for event-driven I/O and SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some event libraries implement such callback hooks:

- [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)
- [libevent](http://libevent.org/)

and all graphical or HTTP server libraries (e.g. Gtk/Glib, Qt, [LibOnion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), ...) provide (or use) such event libraries (around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc).

<sup>Both Glib (from GTK) and QtCore (from Qt) are event libraries usable without any GUI</sup>

Read also about the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)